# React testing library shows Hidden HTML list to be visible

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-testing-library

I am trying to test toggle activities on hover using @testing-library/react. Bellow is my html

```
<section data-testid="currency" className="relative">
    <div className="flex items-center peer hover:cursor-pointer gap-3" >
        <p className="w-8">
            { currencies[currentCurrency] }
        </p>
        <FiChevronDown />
    </div>
    <ul role="currency-list" className="absolute bg-slate-200 -mx-5 pt-3 peer-hover:block hover:block hidden">
        {
            currencies.map((currency, index) => 
                <li key={ index } className="px-5 pb-3 hover:cursor-pointer" 
                    onClick={ () => selectCurrency(index) }>
                    { currency }
                </li>
            )
        }
    </ul>
</section>
```

And bellow is my testing code:

```
it('toggle currency list on mouse over', async () => {
    render(<SelectCurrency />)
    const currencyList = screen.getByRole("currency-list")
    expect(currencyList).not.toBeVisible()
})
```

I am using Tailwind for CSS. I have given the  hidden class and it will be visible on hover of its parent element or its own. It is working fine but testing is failing. Testing says the element is visible. toBeInTheDocument() is also not working.

Another question, the list has the default role 'list'. I am getting a list without giving roles separately using the default 'list' role. But, how to get a specific list when there are multiple lists?

Comment: Related GitHub issue: [testing-library/jest-dom#209](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/209)

Comment: may be this question(and its answer) can be usefull: